# Exclude Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the thing, I am using a JS function, when you click on a menu item with HREF selector which scrolls down to an element with same ID selector. You get the point. Everything is working fine except i want to disable this function for particular links. Here is the code A im using:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
 $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top}, 700);
  return false;
   e.preventDefault();
```

The problem is that this code is applied on every link. Ive tried some stuff but with no success.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Start by determining the criteria you want to exclude them on, and then either change your selector or add a test in the function that checks the target and immediately returns if a condition is met.

Comment: [`$('a[href^="#"]').not(XXXXXX)`](http://api.jquery.com/:not/)

Comment: Yea that worked, thanks epascarello and Quentin...